# A code that prints the running product

Tags: c++, multiplication

How does one create C++ code that prints the running product of every third number.

I don't know if I understand it or not.

Comment: Either increment i inside your loop manually, or increment it in the for loop. Don't do it in both places, as it's too confusing.

Comment: Thank you Neil. I did what you suggested, I got the same output.

Comment: you have overflow, the numbers are just too big to fit multiplication result into any type

Comment: Try to store the sum in `unsigned long long` data type. Hopefully that is large enough.

Comment: Then you'll need to use an arbitrary-size integer class.

Comment: Thank you lizusek .. Neil, I tried using the unsigned long long and it gave me more numbers without the (-) and less Zeroes. Thanks .. Is that the most I can do to

Comment: It is the most with the built-in data types for a typical compiler.

Comment: Well, this is my first semester in computer science :(. That's why I am not familiar with some of the terms you guys use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are running this on (32-bit architecture, 64-bit?) but you might be overflowing an int. Your answer is going to get very large.

Comment: Even `unsigned long long` will only handle up to 136.

Comment: I don't know really if I am running on 32-bit or 64? Some told me that this program can't be done in c++ !! Is that right? I mean, my code is correct, it's just the result is too big to fit, right? The important thing is that my understanding to the question is correct, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say "can't be done" in the Turing sense -- there are techniques for representing and handling very large numbers but it's a ton more work than when native types are sufficient.

Comment: Well, this is my first semester in computer science :(. That's why I am not familiar with some of the terms you guys use.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `sum` is overflowing. Even making it an `unsigned long long` will only handle up to 136. Using `double` for `sum` will get you close -- 481 -- but no data type available in C++ will handle all the way up to 500.

If you absolutely must go to 500, you're going to need to use a class that can support large integer values. You don't say what platform and compiler you're using, but take a look at something like the [BigInteger class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Thanks Carey. I haven't studied classes yet. I am a fresh computer science student

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be a class. It could just be a set of functions. You might find some open source code out there that supports large integers, but if not you would have to write it yourself. That would be an extremely advanced project for a beginning CS student.

Comment: Thank you so much Carey.I guess I am going with using unsigned long long data type as it gives the most results :/.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long product(100);
for (unsigned long i(103); i<=500; i+=3)
{
  product *= i;
  std::cout << product << std::endl;
}
```

So this iterates in steps of 3 every number from 100 to 500 and computes the product then outputs that.

Though as RobP says this will likely overflow, hence my using unsigned long's in the code above.  To learn about detecting that overflow see this:

[How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: Even `unsigned long long` is nowhere near big enough. It barely gets past 100.

Comment: I expected as much but didn't want to do the maths

Comment: Thanks guys. I am started thinking that this is beyond my level!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be accepted, but this prints a product (after all the format was not specified, right?).

```
unsigned long long  product = 1;
std::vector<int> fct;
for (int i = 100; i <= 500; i = i +3)
{
    if ( (i%2) == 0) {
        int r = i / 2;
        fct.push_back( r);
        std::cout << "product:" << product << " * 2";
        std::vector<int>::iterator it = fct.begin();
        while ( it != fct.end()) {
            std::cout << " * " << *it++;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
    product = product * i;
    std::cout << "product:" << product << " * 2";
        std::vector<int>::iterator it = fct.begin();
        while ( it != fct.end()) {
            std::cout << " * " << *it++;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

> product:1 * 2 * 50
>
> product:103 * 2 * 50
>
> product:103 * 2 * 50 * 53
>
> product:11227 * 2 * 50 * 53
>
> product:11227 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56
>
> product:1291105 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56
>
> product:1291105 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56 * 59
>
> (...)
>
> product:2557801186831291169 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56 * 59 * 62 * 65 * 68 *
>   71 * 74 * 77 * 80
>
> product:2557801186831291169 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56 * 59 * 62 * 65 * 68 *
>   71 * 74 * 77 * 80 * 83
>
> (...)
>
> product:9086141910361656411 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56 * 59 * 62 * 65 * 68 *
>   71 * 74 * 77 * 80 * 83 * 86 * 89 * 92 * 95 * 98 * 101 * 104 * 107 *
>   110 * 113 * 116 * 119 * 122 * 125 * 128 * 131 * 134 * 137 * 140 * 143
>   * 146 * 149 * 152 * 155 * 158 * 161 * 164 * 167 * 170 * 173 * 176 * 179 * 182 * 185 * 188 * 191 * 194 * 197 * 200 * 203 * 206 * 209 * 212
>   * 215 * 218 * 221 * 224 * 227 * 230 * 233 * 236 * 239 * 242 * 245
>
> product:9086141910361656411 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56 * 59 * 62 * 65 * 68 *
>   71 * 74 * 77 * 80 * 83 * 86 * 89 * 92 * 95 * 98 * 101 * 104 * 107 *
>   110 * 113 * 116 * 119 * 122 * 125 * 128 * 131 * 134 * 137 * 140 * 143
>   * 146 * 149 * 152 * 155 * 158 * 161 * 164 * 167 * 170 * 173 * 176 * 179 * 182 * 185 * 188 * 191 * 194 * 197 * 200 * 203 * 206 * 209 * 212
>   * 215 * 218 * 221 * 224 * 227 * 230 * 233 * 236 * 239 * 242 * 245 * 248
>
> product:14532515211626403169 * 2 * 50 * 53 * 56 * 59 * 62 * 65 * 68 *
>   71 * 74 * 77 * 80 * 83 * 86 * 89 * 92 * 95 * 98 * 101 * 104 * 107 *
>   110 * 113 * 116 * 119 * 122 * 125 * 128 * 131 * 134 * 137 * 140 * 143
>   * 146 * 149 * 152 * 155 * 158 * 161 * 164 * 167 * 170 * 173 * 176 * 179 * 182 * 185 * 188 * 191 * 194 * 197 * 200 * 203 * 206 * 209 * 212
>   * 215 * 218 * 221 * 224 * 227 * 230 * 233 * 236 * 239 * 242 * 245 * 248

Comment: Thanks lizusek. But I can't present this to my instructor. There are term that I've never seen. I will A+ for cheating :D.

Comment: @user3479130 is there requirement for this to be real multiplication? I don't think so as this really cannot be represented by any fundamental type. Or maybe really you misunderstood the task. Maybe it was just to print every third number?

Comment: what is "running product of a number"? This is a question, ask your colleagues or professor...  ; )

Comment: I don't know. I searched the internet but I couldn't find an answer!

Comment: @user3479130  Because it is not standard thing. I am myself very, very curious what your professor meant and what is an answer. Can you please ping me here when you will know this?

Answer (score 0):

The largest number you con go using integer data type is, 
unsigned long long int b = 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; (18446744073709551615)

In your case the result is even bigger than this number.

That is the twist in this problem. You might have to find a way to handling large numbers. I recommend finding already existing API or algorithm.

I have written a program that does this... I did not test this for edge cases and there can be a better way of doing this.

For now,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

void print_num(deque<int> &num) {
  for(int i=0;i < num.size();i++) {
    cout<<num[i];
  }
  cout<<endl;
}

deque<int> sum(deque<int> &oppA, deque<int> &oppB) {
  if (oppA.size() == 0) return oppB;
  if (oppB.size() == 0) return oppA;

  deque<int> result;
  unsigned int carry = 0;

  deque<int>::reverse_iterator r_oppA = oppA.rbegin();
  deque<int>::reverse_iterator r_oppB = oppB.rbegin();
  while ((r_oppA != oppA.rend()) && (r_oppB != oppB.rend())) {

    int tmp = *r_oppA + *r_oppB + carry;
    result.push_front(tmp % 10);
    carry = tmp / 10;

    r_oppB++;
    r_oppA++;

  }
  while (r_oppA != oppA.rend()) {
    int tmp = *r_oppA + carry;
    result.push_front(tmp % 10);
    carry = tmp / 10;
    r_oppA++;
  }

  while (r_oppB != oppB.rend()) {
    int tmp = *r_oppB + carry;
    result.push_front(tmp % 10);
    carry = tmp / 10;
    r_oppB++;
  }

  return result;
}

deque<int> multiply(deque<int>& multiplicand, deque<int>& multiplier) {

  unsigned int carry = 0;
  deque<int> result;
  int deci_cnt = 0;

  deque<int>::reverse_iterator r_multiplier = multiplier.rbegin();
  deque<int> tmp_result;

  while (r_multiplier != multiplier.rend()) {

    for (int i=0; i<deci_cnt ;i++) {
      tmp_result.push_front(0);
    }

    deque<int>::reverse_iterator r_multiplicand = multiplicand.rbegin();
    while (r_multiplicand != multiplicand.rend()) {
      int tmp = (*r_multiplicand) * (*r_multiplier) + carry;
      tmp_result.push_front(tmp % 10);
      carry = tmp / 10;
      r_multiplicand++;
    }

    if (carry != 0) {
      tmp_result.push_front(carry);
      carry = 0;
    }

    result = sum(result, tmp_result);

    deci_cnt++;
    tmp_result.clear();
    r_multiplier++;
  }

  return result;
}

deque<int> int_to_deque(unsigned long num) {
  deque<int> result;

  if (num == 0) {
    result.push_front(0);
  }

  while (num > 0) {
    result.push_front(num % 10);
    num = num / 10;
  }

  return result;
}

int main() {

  deque<int> num1 = int_to_deque(18446744073709551615ULL);
  deque<int> num2 = int_to_deque(18446744073709551615ULL);

  deque<int> result = multiply(num1, num2);
  print_num(result);

  return 0;
}
```

Output: 340282366920928463426481119284349108225